# How to select character model in creation?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

I want to create a skeleton character in Soulcalibur 5. When I was looking around online I found someone that did create one:[image: skeleton character]
 He says that he loaded a skeleton model at character creation and built it off of that. I did not know you could do that. So my question is how would I go about loading a skeleton model at creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Skeleton Model" is from the Skeleton Costumes 1 DLC and occupies the underwear slot of custom characters. Check your console's store page for the game to purchase it. From what I can see, it should be $0.99

Do note that the Skeleton Model does have some conflicts with certain clothing items (I couldn't tell you which off-hand, since I don't own it)